# Использование openapi.yaml в springdoc

Tags: swagger

Есть простой springboot проект с одним @RestController.
Можно [программно](https://springdoc.org/faq.html#can-i-customize-openapi-object-programmatically) настраивать open api
Хочу сделать тоже самое, но с помощью openapi.yaml файла, как в [swagger-petstore](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-petstore/blob/master/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml) примере.
Создаю нужный openapi.yaml и копирую в /src/main/resources/.
Но когда открываю swagger-ui страницу, вижу значения по умолчанию.
Может кто подсказать, почему не подхватывается yml-файл?